# A writing animation using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please refer [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhijit41/KAaXx/17/),

I have tried to create an animation where a `div` flies in, then text appears one character at a time.

I want more of a smooth *writing* effect - what I have created resembles more of a *typing* effect.

Is there any jquery plugin that does this?
Or can I enhance my code to achieve it?

Comment: As in the font's being drawn out, as if someone were writing it with a pen? This can _sort of_ be done, but not particularly well. No, I will not recommend Flash. That's like recommending I stab myself in the hand ;-P

Comment: Note that your green box doesn't line up with the white one if I resize the window

Comment: yes sir :P i want something like that writing with a pen, cursive to be precise, using a font in which letters are connected would render that effect?

Comment: @Eric green is just to emphasize the effect i know that i have kept floating css for all the divs for now

Comment: btw thanks Eric for the edit means :P

Comment: My point is that the edges of the box do not line up on all screen sizes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be tricky, but you could probably do this using svg animations using the [raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) javascript library. Below some code that's slightly adapted from the [raphael animation demo](http://raphaeljs.com/animation.html) as a proof of concept. Obviously you would have to have several gradual path animations to get the effect that you actually want.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Raphaël · Animation</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://raphaeljs.com/demo.css"media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://raphaeljs.com/demo-print.css"media="print">
        <style media="screen">
            #holder {
                height: 419px;
                margin: -205px 0 0 -305px;
                width: 619px;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://raphaeljs.com/raphael.js"></script>

        <script>
            Raphael.fn.arrow = function (x, y) {
                return this.path(["M", x, y] + "m-10-10l20,0 0-6 10,16 -10,16 0-6 -20,0 0,6 -10-16 10-16z").attr({fill: "#fff", stroke: "none", "stroke-dasharray": "-", "fill-opacity": 0.2});
            };
            window.onload = function () {
                // var r = Raphael("holder", 619, 419),
                var r = Raphael("holder", 619, 419), //Raphael(0, 0, "100%", "100%"),
                    dashed = {fill: "none", stroke: "#666", "stroke-dasharray": "- "};
                // Path 3
                (function () {
                    var el = r.path("M20,290c0-20 40,20 40,0").attr({fill: "none", stroke: "#fff", "stroke-width": 2}),
                        elattrs = [{path: "M20,290c0-20 40,20 40,0c0-20 -40,20 -40,0z"}, {path: "M20,290c0-20 40,20 40,0c"}],
                        now = 1;
                    r.arrow(90, 290).node.onclick = function () {
                        el.stop().animate(elattrs[+(now = !now)], 1000);
                    };
                })();
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="holder"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

As of 2013 there is now [Lazy Line Painter](http://lazylinepainter.info), a jQuery Plugin to create Animations from SVG files. It is built upon Raphaël.